# Identity of a spider found on Cyprus

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

I'm trying to identify a little friendly spider seen in Cyprus. She is brown, around 0.7 inches (2cm) long with white-striped legs, and a small dotted back. This seems like a pumpkin spider, but the head is way too big.

[image: close up of small brown spider with white-striped legs]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Did you observe any behavior that could be added to your question — for example it looks like your spider might be raising its rear legs.  In addition, it would be helpful if you could add a clear photo from the front that shows the pattern of the eyes — this is an important diagnostic feature for many spiders. (Also, note I edited to (I hope) make your post clearer and correct your tag. Spiders are not insects, but instead in a separate group of arthropods that includes scorpions.)

Answer (score 4):

Following the recommendations from [tyersome](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/46609/tyersome) about eye pattern and behavior I was able to identify this little spider as a [**Male Araneus Diadematus**](https://www.eurospiders.com/Araneus_diadematus.htm). They are common garden spiders and harmless, their bite is similar to a bee sting and pose no threat to human life.